OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException using try catch in c#
When I try to find the element I am getting OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException I used try and catch .But still exception is coming.Any suggestion ?
try
{
   await //my element;
}
catch (OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException ex) 
{ 
           
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
      throw ex;
}

I want to catch that exception when it occur from try call

Adding a try/catch block will not make the error disappear, it is just a coding block to catch and usually handle that error. In your specific case, the error means either the selector you used is wrong and no element is found when querying the DOM with such selector - or page is rendered dynamically and the moment you query for that element it was not yet rendered. What is the site url and what is the selector you are using ?

In my case I am checking that the selector on the page is not present ,I expect that to throw that exception but after that exception I want my code to move further

Please [edit] your question to include a [repro]. There is no way we can suggest a fix without seeing more of the code, including the exception message and stack trace.

I understand your problem is not the error happening, but the exception breaking/aborting the flow. If that is true, that is because you are rethrowing the exception (it was just thrown and you just caught it in the catch block) instead of simply handling it.
Remove "throw" and log error or whatever.
Your code will move on to the lines below the try/catch block.
Remark: keep in mind what throw ex does. It resets the callstack. If you do not want to reset it or do not care, you should be using "throw" alone.
But in your case - you do not want "throw" whatsoever :-), so just remove it.

In theory it should work but  in my case it is still showing OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException after the await line in try called

your try block contains a single line only ? could you edit your question and put the very exact line of code that sits there ?

thr is an element I am finding inside the try block  and it is working ok for the positive test case where I am getting that element and then doing assert now I want to check the negative scenario and for which I try to find that element on the screen when it is not present

Summarizing: If you search for an element that is not present, the expected behavior is that the NoSuchElementException  exception will be raised. By wrapping the code statement responsible for that search - you can handle the exception in the catch block and keep the code flowing sequentially to the lines below the try/catch block - without flow being aborted. Using throw inside the catch will have achieve the opposite of what you want - not to abort the flow.

I would really recommend not to handle this type of exceptions in your test code. When an element should not exist, one can use Matching(Be.Not.InDom)
if (X.Find(locator).Matching(Be.Not.InDom))
{
    ...
}

